# Rails 3 - Concerns with Modules or Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm using ActiveSupport::Concern and I know there are a few approaches to organizing these into a /app/model/concern folder for say generic concerns but if I wanted to tie a concern to a specific model I have see a few approaches and would like to see some pros and cons

```
class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Shareable
```

concerns in the /app/models/alert folder

```
class Alert
   module Shareable
      extends ActiveSupport::Concern
```

or

```
module Alert::Shareable
   extends ActiveSupport::Concern
```

or

```
module Alert
   module Shareable
      extends ActiveSupport::Concern
```

Not really sure if there is a best way to do this or if I should use only modules or class module.  I know it is trivial and they all seem to work but organizationally wasn't sure if there is a best approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model is `Alert`, you definitely don't want `module Alert` (#3). #1 and #2 are basically the same, but more often you see the #2 style.

Let me explain a little further.

The `module X::Y` style will only work if `X` has already been defined. It's saying "create this module `Y` under `X` and I don't care if `X` is a class or module, just do it.

For #3, since `Alert` is already defined as a `class`, you'll get this error: `TypeError: Alert is not a module`.

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Austin.  THANK YOU!  I have gotten to a point where I have see all three used and wasn't always 100% if there was a method to the madness of which one to use.  You have cleared it up for me perfectly.  I'm doing a massive refactor now and I love actually understanding the ins and outs of things.  Appreciate your help again!

Comment: No problem. Just think of both classes and modules as constants and nest them according to what makes sense semantically. Classes can go under modules and vice versa. If eventually it makes sense that other things can be shareable, then move it to the top of the namespace. Meaning, don't nest it under Alert. Cheers.

Comment: Agreed, I've had an easier go using the second style, i.e., module Alert::Shareable. If you use the first, i.e., class module, then you run into places where tooling is confused by multiple class definitions of Alert. For example, the Annotate gem gives a superclass mismatch error and won't annotate the Alert model. I've also had some issues in the rails dev console. That said, both styles work fine in the running Rails app.